# Firestore - Update collection field when all subdocuments have a specific field value

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to watch/check all sub documents within a collection in firestore?  I have a collection that has many subdocuments.  Each subdocument has a field called status.  I'm looking for a way to "watch/check" all subdocuments and when each document's status field is "success" the collection can be marked as completed and the end user notified the task is completed.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "the collection can be marked as completed"?

Comment: I'm thinking just a field under the collection called status with the value of "Completed" once all sub documents within that collection are marked as "SUCCESS".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to run a query on the documents in the subcollection to determine if there are any documents not "success" yet.

Alternatively, add a field to your parent document that counts the number of child documents with a "not success" status, update this every time you write/update/delete a status in a child document, and then update the parent document once the count reaches 0.

Comment: Do you have an example of running a query that spans multiple documents within a collection that can be filtered by a field value?    The alternative option is interesting.  I do add a totals field so adding a second one for "not success" that's decreased on each success update is an option.  Which of the two would be less costly on firebase?   These collections can upwards of 1000+ documents.

Comment: Upon reading your answer again I may have misunderstood.  I originally thought you meant that I would have a field that has 1000 "not success" and then as each one becomes success I decrease this number.   However reading your answer again it seems like you're stating that I can have a field that "counts" the child documents?  Do you have an example of this?   Thanks

Comment: 1) That'd just be a query like here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries. Querying subcollections is not any different, except for the path. And since you care about existence of any matching doc, you probably want to limit your query to at most 1 result: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data 2) The count would be in the parent document, and you then increase/decrease it for every relevant write to a document in the subcollection.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still fairly new.  I've been playing around with the query builder since I wrote earlier and do see how the query is able to search the docs.  I think this will work well.   I do still like the second option as well so I'll figure out what I'm going to do.   This gives me an idea to work with! Appreciate it.